# Can't pass value from option value and display on table using jQuery AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the image in inspect element when I clicked the option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcp1a.png)

this is the option [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k08Kq.png)

and show an alert
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PmRi.png)

This is my HTML

This is my select tag and option value

```
<div class="dt_limit">Limit :
    <select id="dt_limit" style="width:60px;" onchange="javascript:load_timesheet_logs_list_dt();">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript Function. This is the function I created using jQuery AJAX. The url is my php path directory, I'm not sure about the query variable that I concatenated in url

```
function load_timesheet_logs_list_dt() {
    var data = $('#dt_limit').val();
    var pathname =location.search;
    var convert_data = parseInt(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'attendance/manage',
        data:  ({ data: data}) ,
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

This is my PHP Function
the $per_page variable is just for experimenting only
I manually created that variable for showing data, the code works fine but I want to make it dynamic when selecting a value from select tag on my html then show the data on my table depending on the value selected in option tag**

```
function manage() {
    $per_page = $_GET['data'];
    $page_number = (int) $_GET['pageID'];

    if ($page_number > 0) {
        $page_number--;
        $start_record = $page_number * $per_page;
    } else {
        $start_record = $page_number;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think its '$_GET['pageID']'  wrong get variable

Comment: where you php function called?

Comment: Srsly I don't know, do you have suggestion?

Comment: manage() ; where is your function call?

Comment: On my jQuery AJAX url?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where **exactly** is that code going wrong? Does the AJAX request trigger the proper URL? Does it contain the expected data?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$per_page = 100;
```

to

```
$per_page = $_GET['data'];
```

Comment: How to do it in ajax? Can you help me?

Comment: put alert(data); below the success function


`success: function(data){
 alert(data);`


put print_r($_GET); below the controller function




`function manage() {
  print_($_GET);exit();`


what was the alert value...???

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please see the images above, I edited the questions to show it clearly

Comment: **var query = window.location.search;**
what did you get when `alert(query);`

Answer (score 0):

Get method using this construct: `$_GET['data']`. I have tested this.

index.html

```
<div class="dt_limit">Limit :
    <select id="dt_limit" style="width:60px;" onchange="javascript:load_timesheet_logs_list_dt();">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function load_timesheet_logs_list_dt() {
    var data = $('#dt_limit').val();
    var pathname =location.search;
    var convert_data = parseInt(data);
    var query = window.location.search;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: query + '/post.php',
        data:  ({ data: data}) ,
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

post.php

```
manage();
function manage() {
    $per_page = 100;
    $page_number = (int) $_GET['data'];

    if ($page_number > 0) {
        $page_number--;
        $start_record = $page_number * $per_page;
    } else {
        $start_record = $page_number;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error said **Not Found** but in console I can view the value of the option when I clicked it.

Comment: You should at least provide some explanation in your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @ Nico Haase thank you for your response will explain

Comment: Please see the images above, I edited the questions to show it clearly

Comment: In PHP part, I just want it to be clear. The variable $per_page, I want this to be dynamic, when I clicked the value (ex: 100) in option, it will show the data in the table.